# Convert Swift Dictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: swift

I have created a Swift Dictionary object

```
var params = ["first_name": firstNameTextField.text,
              "last_name": lastNameTextField.text,
              "company": companyTextField.text,
              "email_address": emailTextField.text,
              "phone_number": phoneTextField.text]
```

Next, I have ObjC framework which I connected to my Swift app.
There is an object inside with property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *fields;
```

I'm trying to assign it this way

```
object.fields = params
```

And got an error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'NSMutableDictionary!'
```

I also tried to do it this way

```
var params = ["first_name": firstNameTextField.text,
              "last_name": lastNameTextField.text,
              "company": companyTextField.text,
              "email_address": emailTextField.text,
              "phone_number": pnoneTextField.text].mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary

object.fields = params
```

It compiled well, but I got runtime error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: 
attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

I have all my fields printed and they aren't nil:

```
println(firstNameTextField.text)
println(lastNameTextField.text)
println(companyTextField.text)
println(emailTextField.text)
println(pnoneTextField.text)

...

1
2
3
5
4
```

Any ideas?

Comment: But "1", "2" and so on are not text that you are really keeping in a first name field and a last name field - are they???? Seems to me more likely that they are _all_ nil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `parms.bridgeToObjectiveC()`. That may give you an NSDictionary rather than an NSMutableDictionary, though.

Comment: Thanks, it works this way!  var params = [...].bridgeToObjectiveC() as NSMutableDictionary

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as of beta 6?
let asdf = ["asdf": "qwer"].bridgeToObjectiveC()
'Dictionary<Key, Value>' does not have a member named 'bridgeToObjectiveC'

Comment: I think they removed `bridgeToObjectiveC` from the language in beta 5.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that this code initializing your `params`...

```
var params = ["first_name": firstNameTextField.text,
              "last_name": lastNameTextField.text,
              "company": companyTextField.text,
              "email_address": emailTextField.text,
              "phone_number": phoneTextField.text]
```

...might be happening before you have any text field outlets hooked up. What I would suggest is that you set this `var` as `@lazy`, type it as `Dictionary<String,String>`, and set it to a called closure that returns this dictionary. Thus the dictionary won't be created until later, when you actually access `self.params`.

Comment: No, as you can see println function prints proper values. So I can say that all TextFields were initialised before