# How to convert NSDictionary to NSObject in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have a meta variable `NSObject` in a viewcontroller that I intend to be able to receive any kind of object from the parent viewcontroller that pushes it. I also have a type variable that will determine how I typecast and interpret this `NSObject` inside the viewcontroller.

The problem is when I tried to cast an `NSDictionary` into `NSObject` in the parent, Xcode warns that that type of typecasting will always fail.

Code that I have tried:

```
childVc.meta = ["title":"test"] as! NSObject; // warning: cast from '[String:String?]' to unrelated type 'NSObject' always fails.

let data = ["title":"test"];
childVc.meta = data as! NSObject; // warning: cast from '[String:String?]' to unrelated type 'NSObject' always fails.


let data = ["title":"test"];
childVc.meta = data as NSObject; // error: cannot convert value of type '[String:String?]' to type 'NSObject' in coercion.


let data = ["title":"test"] as! NSObject; // warning: cast from '[String:String?]' to unrelated type 'NSObject' always fails.
childVc.meta = data;
```

But the opposite typecasting always works:

```
let unwrappedMeta = self.meta as! NSDictionary;
```

Oh btw, I know that swift doesn't need semicolon at the end. It's just my habit from obj-c and swift looks like doesn't care about it, so don't let this semicolon distract us. :)

Comment: an NSDictionary is already an NSObject... have you tried not casting it?

Comment: in any case, that is a swift dictionary, not an NSDictionary, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24173564/1219956)

Comment: Why can't I reproduce this? I got a warning saying it will always succeed!

Comment: I don't know why, but today when I tried this again, everything works. -_- from direct assignment, even typecasting, all works, and yes, now I get warning that it will always succeed. #facepalm I think my Xcode was acting out again. anyway, thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an optional value in dictionary, seems not to be NSDictionary.

```
  // warning: cast from '[String:String?]'
```

Try to cast it as `AnyObject`

Comment: Yes, that's what I then learn through the hard way. I thought NSObject and AnyObject is the same. But now I see that even NSArray and Swift Array themselves are different to each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use like this:

```
var traitsDic : NSDictionary! = ["title":"test"]
var traits = traitsDic as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: He's not using segment analytics and if he was the he could have got answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271230/objc-to-swift-conversion-of-nsdictionary-to-nsobject-anyobject

Comment: @AyathKhan hi. I don't know that that is called segment analytics. I've tried to find basic tutorial about that before, but couldn't find any. can you give some recommendation about it?

Comment: @Mr. Bond is NSDictionary and Dictionary the same class?